# I can't inject the bean of TestEntityManager in the jpa repository test class

Tags: java, spring, testing

When injecting a bin into a test class, the repository jpa underlines testEntityManager in red. I can't figure out what the problem is.

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringTgBot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringTgBot</name>
    <description>Telegrambot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vdurmont</groupId>
            <artifactId>emoji-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is repository

```
import io.project.SpringTgBot.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User getUserById(long id);
}
```

This is repositoryTest

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class UserRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager testEntityManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
}
```

I had no problem with this before in projects, but now I have no idea what it might be related to.
Error: Could not autowire. no beans of 'testEntityManager' type found

Comment: Just wondering, how come you need a variable of type TestEntityManager for this test class?

Comment: From the repository testing guides. In most cases, a variable of this type is used.